# how to select latest data using self join or other method?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE USER ( 
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(50),
  `status` VARCHAR(50),
  `dateupdated` DATETIME
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

If the data, has an `ID` as primary key, then the username can be repeated, let's say I have 3 users, and all of them had a status update yesterday and today. Now my question is, how to select only the latest status updates from each user ?, here's my solution

```
   SELECT user.`username`, latest.status AS latest_status , user.`dateupdated` 
     FROM USER 
LEFT JOIN USER AS latest ON user.`id` = latest.id 
 ORDER BY dateupdated DESC;
```

...but it seem wrong, because it "also" printed out the data dated yesterday, so how to do that in order to get the exact latest data only for each users and avoid printing out the past datas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but to get the latest per user you have to add an extra sorting condition in your JOIN, and a where condition:

```
SELECT  u.username, u.status AS latest_status , u.dateupdated 
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN USER u2
 ON u.username=u2.username 
AND u.dateupdated < u2.dateupdated  -- see extra JOIN cond?
WHERE u2.dateupdated IS NULL        -- see extra WHERE cond?
ORDER BY dateupdated DESC;
```

What this does is join `USER` to itself not only within username, but such that `u`'s `dateupdated` is less than `u2`s. Since this a `LEFT JOIN`, if there is a `u.dateupdated` such that there is *no greater `u2.updated` for the same `username`*, then the `u2.updated` is set to NULL.

But these `u.dateupdated` are *precisely* the maximum `dateupdated` for that user, and hence we add the `WHERE` condition in to grab these rows.